# Laravel Lumen PHPUnits [ReflectionException] Class command.laracasts.seed does not exist

Tags: php, laravel, phpunit, codeception, laravel-seeding

I'm running a PHP project based on Laravel `Lumen` 
Whenever I run my test suite (`CodeCeption` framework), I run the `artisan` command `$this->artisan("db:Seed");` at the begining of each test (in the `setup` method) and I get the following error:

```
  [ReflectionException] Class command.laracasts.seed does not exist  

#1  /app/vendor/illuminate/container/Container.php:753
#2  /app/vendor/illuminate/container/Container.php:631
#3  /app/vendor/illuminate/container/Container.php:586
#4  /app/vendor/laravel/lumen-framework/src/Application.php:230
#5  /app/vendor/illuminate/console/Application.php:228
#6  /app/vendor/illuminate/console/Application.php:242
#7  /app/vendor/illuminate/support/ServiceProvider.php:267
#8  /app/vendor/illuminate/console/Application.php:147
#9  /app/vendor/illuminate/console/Application.php:70
#10 /app/vendor/laravel/lumen-framework/src/Console/Kernel.php:165
```

For information I don't get the error if I run one test class at a time, I only get it when I run a test suite.